# How do I replace the little icon in the upper-left corner of a form in VB6?

Tags: vb6

VB6 forms have a little picture in the upper-left that controls the menu for Close, Move, Restore, and so forth (what is the name of that menu, by-the-by?), and in my current application a previous owner has replaced that icon with a corporate logo.

[image: (This bit here is what I mean)]

Sadly it is now the wrong corporate logo and it now needs replacing. Has anyone any idea how to do this? I can't see anything in the properties page that looks like it does that job.

Comment: Did you try the `Icon` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check on the Project-Properties, Make tab.  The Icon dropdown should have one of your forms selected.  You can then change the Icon property on that form to be a different icon.

**Edit:** I initially read this as just about the main application icon, which is what the above steps will be setting.  Each individual non-child form can have it's own icon, set by the Icon property for that form.

Comment: Yes, I see now. I was deceived by the property apparently being unset, as it doesn't show any file name or anything of that sort. To unset it though (I don't have a new .ico to hand) I had to edit the .frm file. Thanks to all answerers.

Comment: You can clear the set icon from the properties window.  When an icon for a form is set you are correct that the graphic isn't displayed, but the Icon property will display as '(Icon)'.  Select that text (don't click the ellipsis button) then press the Delete key.  The Icon property should then show as '(None)'.  Voila!

Comment: Ah! Thanks; that'd probably be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think previous developer could override some WinApi class with context menu

Answer (score 1):

Post 2 on [this page](http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/31328/changing-the-applicationsprograms-icon-vb6/).